# Python: Excluding Numbers From A Text Corpus

Tags: python-3.x, text, corpus

I'm tring to make a corpus of unique lexemes (with their frequencies) which have been extracted from a Persian text file. I turned the text into a list based on which I created a list of unique tokens. I wanted to exclude any numeral token before writing the final list into the corpus so I wrote:

```
FileObj = open ('TextOfTexts.txt', 'r', encoding = 'UTF8')
CorpObj = open ('MyCorpus.txt', 'w', encoding = 'UTF8')
FOList = FileObj.read().split (' ')
DigiList = re.findall (r'\b[+-]?\d+\b', FileObj.read()) #List of numeral tokens
UniTokens = list (set(FOList))    #List of unique tokens

for UniLex in UniTokens:
    if UniLex not in DigiList: #This if-Block's supposed 2 exclude numbers
        UniCount = FOList.count (UniLex) # Counts frequencies of tokens
        CorpObj.write (UniLex + '\t' + UniCount + '\n')
FileObj.close()
CorpObj.close()
```

I've tested the contents of DigiList. The RegEx correctly lists all integers that exist in my main text file. But my text corpus has still got those integers with their frequencies inside it. What am I doing wrong? How can I drop integers down before they enter into my corpus?

P.S.:
I also wrote the if-Block like this but it didn't do my desired job as well:

```
if UniLex in DigiList:
    continue
else:
    ...
```

Comment: On my laptop, your code works. Can you post a small sample of TextOfTexts.txt? (also try deleting the output file, just in case)

Comment: @Eric Levieil: I've placed a File Removal procedure on the start of my main code which purges every previously generated text file.

Comment: I uploaded the whole text file so you may download the whole thing. It's only +1.7 Mb in size: [URL=http://wikisend.com/download/493844/ZebraAllNormalized.txt]ZebraAllNormalized.txt[/URL]

Comment: @Eric Levieil: I hope you don't have problem to open a Persian text. I forgot to rename it to fit to code.